# isometry of $H^2$ representing the conjugacy class

Tags: geometry

I read [paper](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~farb/papers/flm.pdf) p.4, there is a sentence I cannot understand:

> $\alpha$ is a essential simple closed curve in a closed oriented surface $\Sigma$, let $g_{\alpha}$ be an isometry of $\mathbf H^2$ reperesenting the conjugacy class of $\alpha$.

Could you explain it? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the post to use a free source, since I didn't have access to the one you referenced. But I couldn't find yor exact wording in that text. So please check that this is not due to differences in the text, and if it is, feel free to roll back my change.

Answer (score 1):

I did not read the paper but I assume that the surface $\Sigma$ is equipped with a hyperbolic metric. This means that we can identify its universal cover with hyperbolic plane and it's fundamental group with an isometry group of $H^2$. An unbased loop in $\Sigma$ then determines a conjugacy class in the fundamental group which explains the sentence.